# Change Mediaquery response

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting my studies in fullstack and we were just shown bootstrap. I'm doing this site responsive, and I modified the menu bar to my please. The only thing I'd like to change is the menu to colapse into the toggle button only below 600px-ish wide (aka for phones). Any assistance will be appreciated
html

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Academia</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tienda</a>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nosotros</a>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the *How it works* section of Bootstrap navbar documentation, you can use `navbar-expand-sm` instead of `navbar-expand-lg`. This will collapse the navbar only on screens smaller than 576px(sm).

Comment: Thanks mate, really appreciate it